# Salmon tximport

Tags: rna-seq, deseq2, tximport

I ran bulk `RNA-seq` experiment and got `quant.sf` file. Now, I am struggling with understanding what `tximport` package does and how to use it correctly. My ultimate goal is to feed the data into `DESeq2` for differential expression analysis. In the documentation:

http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/tximport/man/tximport.pdf

We have:

```
samples <- read.table(file.path(dir,"samples.txt"), header=TRUE)
files <- file.path(dir,"salmon", samples$run, "quant.sf")
```

I do not understand what are these `samples.txt`. It is not generated by `salmon`, so I suppose that I need to write it myself. How then? What is the correct format for the file? And what if I want to feed just one sample in? That is actually what I want initially: process each sample separately. Could anyone explain step by step how we could utilize `tximport` when we have just one `quant.sf` file to get to raw count matrix to feed it into `DeSeq2`?

Comment: I suppose you could write a `samples.txt` file with a single sample, but there's not much point in processing the samples separately because the first step of `DESeq2` is to calculate size factors, which requires comparisons across samples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, `samples.txt` is not generated by Salmon (or any other transcript abundance quantifiers). From [documentation](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/data/experiment/vignettes/tximportData/inst/doc/tximportData.html), you can find a [link](http://www.geuvadis.org/web/geuvadis) to an example of how `samples.txt` should look like.

Note: At the moment, the server is unavailable (I got an `Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable`) - I'd suggest you get directly in contact with the owners / [authors](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/data/experiment/vignettes/tximportData/inst/doc/tximportData.html).

Luckily, there is a call of the function importing `samples.txt` file in the [doc](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/data/experiment/vignettes/tximportData/inst/doc/tximportData.html) itself (variable `samples`), so you can get an idea of ow you have to structure it:

```
> samples

##   pop center                assay    sample experiment       run
## 1 TSI  UNIGE NA20503.1.M_111124_5 ERS185497  ERX163094 ERR188297
## 2 TSI  UNIGE NA20504.1.M_111124_7 ERS185242  ERX162972 ERR188088
## 3 TSI  UNIGE NA20505.1.M_111124_6 ERS185048  ERX163009 ERR188329
## 4 TSI  UNIGE NA20507.1.M_111124_7 ERS185412  ERX163158 ERR188288
## 5 TSI  UNIGE NA20508.1.M_111124_2 ERS185362  ERX163159 ERR188021
## 6 TSI  UNIGE NA20514.1.M_111124_4 ERS185217  ERX163062 ERR188356
```

As an alternate workaround, find the `samples.txt` format directly from [tximportData Bioconductor page](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/tximportData.html):

1. download [source code](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.6.0.tar.gz)
2. extract
3. navigate to: `[...]/tximportData 2/inst/extdata`
4. read content of `samples.txt`.